# Multiple substitions specified in non-position format error

Tags: java, android, xml, string, android-resources

I having the error "Multiple substitions specified in non-position format error" for the following string resource:

```
<string name="stCrewmanBlockedEnemy">The %1$s has blocked the enemy attack! (dice: %2$d + skill: %3d$d) vs (dice: %4$d + skill: %5$d)</string>
```

However the substitutions are in positional format...

I know there are other questions in stackoverflow with the same topic but I don't think they answer my question. Any ideas?

Edit: I've narrowed down the problem to the presence of the exclamation point and the two points(:). However souldn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out I had a typo with the extra d in the third parameter.

Problem solved.